# Unbalanced TCDL tags when using a tag renderer on broker query

Tags: tcdl, tridion-docs

I'm using the new IfTagRenderer that comes with Tridion DX to try and render out some TCDL tags that exist in content in my broker database. These TCDL tags represent ish conditions used to filter content originating from the Tridion Docs CMS:

e.g.

```
<tcdl:If xmlns:tcdl=\"http://www.sdl.com/web/DXA/Format\" condition=\"(Test=Print) ...> ... </tcdl:If>
```

I'm getting this:

```
com.tridion.transformer.TCDLTransformerException: Unbalanced tags in TCDL file
Closing Tag tcdl:If does not match :
```

even though I can clearly see that my TCDL tags are balanced.

Right before the error, I also see:

```
WARN  TagHandlerRegistry - There is no a handler for tag: 'tcdl:If condition="(Test=Print)" xmlns:tcdl="http://www.sdl.com/web/DXA/Format" type="ish:Condition"'.
```

which indicates to me that the opening TCDL tags are not being recognized, for some reason.

The TCDLEngine configuration in my cd_dynamic_conf looks like this:

[image]

The IfTagRenderer comes in the udp-cis-ish-dynamic-11.0.0-1024.jar file packaged with the Sites 9 install media at /Tridion/Content Delivery/roles/content/ish-cartridge/lib.

Comment: It seems that the TCDLEngine is unable to operate on any tcdl tags that include attributes (e.g. condition="...", etc.), seeing that the closing tcdl:If tag is recognized, but not the opening tag. But that is very strange, since the IfTagRenderer appears to be set up to read this attributes and render the tags accordingly (see udp-cis-ish-dynamic-11.0.0-1024.jar).

Comment: Do you actually escape the quotes for the attributes in the source? Or was that just a mistake when posting the question here?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue in my OOTB setup, In order to fix this issue.

To add the below configuration in the **cd_dynamic_conf.xml** file in your content service.

```
<TCDLEngine>
    <DefaultTags Name="${tcdltags:-combined}"/>
</TCDLEngine>
```

Refer to the SDL [documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v2/GUID-A9C9FA5B-0971-4631-B572-5D66A064DE83)

I hope it will fix your issue.